# List of all directory and file using Appache-Common io return UncheckedException

Tags: android, android-studio, filesystems, guava, scoped-storage

this is the appache code bellow

```
 val newFile =FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(EXTERNAL_STORAGE,TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE,TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
```

from the above code getting error

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data
```

Comment: This is pretty obvious-  you don't have access to that directory.  Did you ask for both manifest and runtime permissions?  Also, what is EXTERNAL_STORAGE?  If its a string, you shouldn't assume what external storage is-  an OEM can mount it anywhere.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() . all permission granted. now import guava and it will work fine .

Comment: val allFiles = Files.fileTraverser().breadthFirst(EXTERNAL_STORAGE)